# Recursively delete all files/folders older than 14days?

Tags: php, scripting, delete-file

My hoster offers PHP as scripting language and I want to setup a CRON. The CRON is basically a GUI where I can enter the script path and script language (PHP).
I need a small script which runs recursively over all folders and files, checking the age and deleting all files older than e.g. 14days.
The PHP needs to be standalone, so that I can be copied to the .php file.
PHP version is up to 5.4.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a big fan spoon-feeding whole scripts, but here are some pointers.

You can get a list of all files and folders in a path using an `RecursiveDirectoryIterator`, passing this to an `RecursiveIteratorIterator` can make the tree structure flat so you can loop trough it. For a small script I'd probably just filter inside that loop, if you think you might need more flexibility (for example pluggable strategies) later on you should check out `FilterIterator` and `RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator`.